# Microsoft linker spontaneously creating library

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker

I'm trying to compile a C program (specifically, the Python interpreter) as a plain statically linked 64-bit Windows binary. My command line looks like this:

```
cl /DPy_BUILD_CORE ... /link Advapi32.lib Shell32.lib User32.lib
```

where ... is the long list of source files and include directory specifications, and the library specifications I added as necessary to fix unresolved symbol errors. I'm getting linker output that looks like (after the C compiler has finished running):

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:getbuildinfo.exe 
Advapi32.lib 
Shell32.lib 
User32.lib 
getbuildinfo.obj 
(lots more .obj's)
   Creating library getbuildinfo.lib and object getbuildinfo.exp
```

... and then a weird error that I'm still trying to figure out, but maybe I might have a better chance if I understand another aspect of the behavior of the linker here.

Why is it creating a library? I didn't tell it to do that. It's only supposed to be creating a `.exe`.

In particular, I tried a small test case with just a couple of trivial C source files and otherwise the exact same command line, and it behaved as expected, creating only the `.exe` and not trying anything with libraries. The only differences are in the number and contents of the C source files, but I wouldn't have thought the contents of a C source file could change the behavior of the linker.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you (or has anyone) used `dllexport` in the source? It's possible to export functions from an exe.

Comment: Ah! Yes, they have indeed.